# countdown page in javaScript and HTML is not redirected to another page after countdown is end

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, countdown

can anyone please please help me?? im stuck in a problem
I am using a pure JavaScript with index.html for  count down timer that I shared below to redirect to a URL when the coundown is end but its not working as im expecting im toooo close.My code work perfect but the problem is after countdown end page is not redirected to other page thats my problem...

```
    const daysEl = document.getElementById("days");
    const hoursEl = document.getElementById("hours");
    const minsEl = document.getElementById("mins");
    const secEl = document.getElementById("sec");
    
    const bd = "april 8,2021 00:00:00";
    function countdown() {
        const bdDate = new Date(bd);
        const currentDate = new Date();
    
        const seconds = (bdDate - currentDate);
    
        const days = Math.floor(seconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    
        const hours = Math.floor((seconds % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    
        const mins = Math.floor((seconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        const sec = Math.floor((seconds % (1000 * 60)) / (1000));
    
    
        daysEl.innerHTML = formatime(days);
        hoursEl.innerHTML = formatime(hours);
        minsEl.innerHTML = formatime(mins);
        secEl.innerHTML = formatime(sec);
    
    
        function formatime(time) {
            return time < 10 ? `0${time}` : time;
        }
         function timeout()
        {window.location.href="boom.html"}
    }
    
    countdown();
    setInterval(countdown,1000);
    setTimeout(timeout(),secEl)
    
    **and this is my HTML code**
    
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title> Coundown Timer </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
            <script src="index.js" defer>  </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>Birthday Countdown<

/h1>
       <div class="countdown-container">
        <div class="days-count">
            <p class="big-text" id="days" >0</p>
            <span>days </span>
    
        </div>
    
        <div class="hours-count">
            <p class="big-text" id="hours" > 0 </p>
            <span>     hours </span>
    
        </div>
        
        <div class="mins-count">
            <p class="big-text" id="mins" > 0 </p>
            <span>   mins </span>
            </div>
    
            <div class="sec-count">
                <p class="big-text" id="sec" > 0 </p>
                <span> sec </span>
        
            </div>
    
        </div>
    
    
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Remove `()` on this line: `setTimeout(timeout(),secEl)` (you don't want to call the function, you just want to pass it so that it will be called later). And move your `function timeout() {...}` outside of the `countdown` function so that it becomes accessible from where you refer to it

Comment: You can also just use a `<meta>` tag in your `<head>`: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=boom.html"/>`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#examples